# Is there a scriptural statement anywhere elevating Rig Veda Samhita over the rest of Shruti?

Tags: rig-veda

From what I understand there is a lot of overlap between Rig Veda Samhita and the other Vedas.  Atharva Veda is considered a late addition to the Vedic corpus.  At least linguistically, Rig Veda Samhita is the oldest Hindu scripture (although other works occasionally have older material).

Comment: samaveda is said to be the best among vedas not rigveda. Rigveda is counted first but the best is samaveda according to upnishads and bhagawata geeta.

Comment: that maybe for its music,  but aren't the sama veda verses mostly from the rig veda? also my question relates to authority - is rig veda samhita he ultimate authority in hinduism?

Comment: No not scriptually but now being oldest it has been given importance like it does not have caste etc apart from purush sukta's one verse which is thought to be later added ,respect of women etc. Although samaveda is recognised as best. apart all vedas are great.

Comment: if rig veda samhita contradicts some other portion of shruti,which prevails? @fierce lord

Comment: wiki says "Almost all of the 1,875 verses found in Samaveda are taken from different parts of the Rigveda, either once or as repetition, and rewritten in a chant song form."

Comment: that is known to me but may be there is some speciality in sama veda because of which it is said to be best i shall quote some verses from scriptures for sama and compare with rigveda position in upnishads if you want it to be in your answer.

Comment: thanks @fierce lord.  clearly "shruti" is vast and heterogeneous and I want to know if there are gradations in their authoritativeness.

Comment: I would prepare answer then @SK ;) and it's not about authoritativeness it's about the result by reading only one of them i will give answer tommorow. Well good night.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:— This answer compares the greatness and result given by each veda as per prashna upnishsda and refrence from bhagawata-geeta rest all vedas are great.**

> 1. Then Satyakama Saibhya
>      asked him, "Godman, he
>      who among men mentally
>      fixes his mind upon Aum
>      until the end of his life,
>      which world he wins by
>      that?
> 2. To him he said,
>      "Satyakama, this very
>      transcendental and
>      immanent Brahman,
>      indeed, is that Aum only.
>      Therefore, the
>      knowledgeable one arrives
>      at one or the other
>      through this means only."
> 3. If he meditates upon
>      the one letter (A), having
>      attained equanimity
>      quickly by that alone, he
>      attains the physical world.
>      The Rics lead him to the
>      world of humans, and
>      there through austerities,
>      the practice of celibacy,
>      endowed with faith, he
>      experiences greatness.
> 4. Now, if (he meditates)
>      upon the two letters (AU)
>      the attains the subtle
>      world. Led by the Yajus
>      through the mid-region, he
>      is lifted to the world of the
>      moon. Having experienced
>      supernatural existence, he
>      returns again.
> 5. Again, he who meditates
>      upon the Supreme Self
>      with the three letters of
>      Aum, he becomes endowed
>      with the light of the sun.
>      Just as a snake is freed
>      from its slough, in the
>      same manner he becomes
>      free from sin. Led by the
>      Samans, he is lifted to the
>      world of Brahman. In the
>      congregation of living
>      entities, he sees the
>      highest of the high and the
>      Person hidden in the
>      persons.
> 6. The three letters are
>      within the confines of
>      death. They should be
>      yoked and applied
>      together. By applying (the
>      unified Aum) in kriya yoga,
>      the awakened one does
>      not waver in the external,
>      internal, intermediate and
>      self-absorbed states.
> 7. The knowledgeable one
>      knows **this world by the
>      Riks**, the mid-region by the
>      Yajus, **and That (Brahman
>      world) by the Samans.**
>      However, with the help of
>      Aum, the learned one
>      attains that which is the
>      highest, calm, free from
>      old age and death,
>      harmonious, without fear
>      and supreme.
>
> **—[prashna upnishada: 4th prashna](http://www.hinduwebsite.com/prasna1.asp)**

It can be seen that om yet have place above all vedas.

**Bhagawata geeta**

> वेदानां सामवेदोऽस्मि
>   देवानामस्मि वासव: |
>   इन्द्रियाणां मनश्चास्मि
>   भूतानामस्मि चेतना || 22||
>
> vedānām — amongst the
>   Vedas ; sāma-vedaḥ — the
>   Sāma Veda ; asmi— I
>   am ; devānām — of all the
>   celestial gods ; asmi— I
>   am ; vāsavaḥ̣— Indra ;
>   indriyāṇām— of amongst
>   the senses ; manaḥ — the
>   mind ; ca— and ; asmi — I
>   am ; bhūtānām —
>   amongst the living
>   beings ; asmi — I am ;
>   chetanā— consciousness
>   Translation
>
> BG 10.22 : **I am the
>   Sāma Veda amongst the
>   Vedas**, and Indra
>   amongst the celestial
>   gods. Amongst the
>   senses I am the mind;
>   amongst the living
>   beings I am
>   consciousness.